# Why does Ubuntu include accounts for packages that aren't installed?

Tags: security, accounts, passwd-file

Why does Ubuntu include accounts for packages that aren't installed (such as gnats, irc,...)? Seems the accounts should be created as needed when the packages are installed, not sitting there in the off chance someone may want to install the package.

From a security standpoint, extra accounts introduce extra attack targets. Yes, they are configured without valid shells or passwords, but the more accounts, the more likely someone can make an unseen typo to open up an account.

Comment: That is strange... they should be created when the relevant package is installed.

Comment: Agree, but this has been the case for Ubuntu server for a while now, at least since 14.04 and probably 12.04 (don't have systems that old anymore so can't confirm). When installing the OS, when it gets to package installation, I always select OpenSSH and nothing else, but those accounts are always there.